# How to update Python datetime object with timezone offset given in such format: "+0300"?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone-offset

Given a datetime.datetime object like that:

```
datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 22, 9, 24, 20, 386060)
```

I get client timezone offset in such format: "+0300" and need to represent the datetime.datetime object considering this offset.

For example, the object above should look like this:

```
datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 22, 12, 24, 20, 386060)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***IIUC***, you have a datetime object that represents UTC and want to convert to a UTC offset of 3 hours. You can do that like

```py
import datetime

dt = datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 22, 9, 24, 20, 386060)

# assuming this is UTC, we need to set that first
dt = dt.replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

# now given the offset
offset = "+0300"

# we can convert like
converted = dt.astimezone(datetime.datetime.strptime(offset, "%z").tzinfo)
```

```
>>> converted
datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 22, 12, 24, 20, 386060, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=10800)))
```